# Network Error when invoking Google Now

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, system-error, google-now

When I try to invoke Google Now by swiping up from the Home button, I get the message "Network error.  Check your network connections and try again".  I have a solid WiFi signal, and searches from the search bar work fine.
I get the same message when I go into settings after launching Google Search and try to enable Google Now.

ASUS Transformer Prime,  Android 4.1.1

Comment: I received the 4.1.1 update back in September, but hadn't tried Google Now until recently - thus it's never worked for me.

Comment: Tried clearing app data for Google Search?

Comment: @SurajBajaj - great idea, but it didn't help.

Comment: I am getting this same issue on my brand new Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: Decided to take another crack at this and uninstalled updates to Google Search, cleared cache and data, and reapplied updates, but still no go.

Comment: I know you're saying you "received" the update, but just to clarify, are you on the official update channel, or are you using a custom rooted ROM?

Comment: Have you tried using another language for Google Now? There's a separate setting for the language in the Google Now menu.

Comment: @harsha - completely stock, not rooted

Comment: @bob - tried switching from English (us) to English (uk) and back, still the same message.  Also tried switching to another Google account.

Comment: From Googling around this seems to be a problem others have experienced, a commonly suggested solution seems to be reinstalling/overwriting the Google Now .apk

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: @ZnewmaN - I'm in the US

Comment: @Peanut - without rooting, I think I'm limited to what I've already done -- uninstall updates back to the "factory" version and then reinstall them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found the answer.   I had four Google accounts - one of them could not sync because it required domain policy to be enforced, and I hadn't allowed that.   I connected the tablet to my laptop and used adb logcat to see what was being logged when the error was displayed:

```
I/GLSUser (28125): GLS error: DeviceManagementRequiredOrSyncDisabled <<account name redacted>> oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/personal_derived_data https://www.googleapis.com/auth/paths.notifications
V/GoogleLoginService(28125): Returning error intent with: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gsf.login/com.google.android.gsf.login.LoginActivity}
E/Velvet.VelvetNetworkClient( 4564): Failed to get auth token
```

(these messages were repeated several times).

I guessed that the errant account may have been involved (even though it was not the account I was trying to active Now with), removed the account from the device and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Google Now is not available in countries and languages as yet, so you may be in a country were it is not supported. You can still search on Google's homepage, or I suppose you could try a proxy or flashing your phone in such a way to make it believe it is somewhere else in the world were Google Now works

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm in the US, and English (US) is my default language.