# Is it possible to use the Google Play Store without having a mobile provider?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store

I am trying to install Skype and other applications on my brand new Android tablet but I keep getting stuck with a message:

> ```
> Can't establish a reliable connection to the server
> This could be a temporary problem...
> If it continues, call Customer Care
> ```

The tablet is running Android 4.0.3
It's a cheap tablet that I ordered from a website for the purpose of doing my own software development. I am using it in Japan. I don't have any contract with any mobile provider. I can successfully access the Internet via WiFi. I tried opening TCP and UDP ports on the router after reading some other threads on similar problems. I updated the Google Play Store apk version 3.4.7 with version 3.10.10 which I downloaded to my Windows PC and transferred with an SD card to the tablet.

It's getting quite frustrating after almost one week of fighting with this problem.
I would appreciated any help or suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible, all WiFi only tablets don't have mobile providers (Nexus for example) and they should work fine. Did you try the call Customer Care bit?

Comment: Care to enclose a logcat of when attempting to connect to play store - there might be something in there...

Comment: What kind of tablet is it (Name, Brand, etc.)?

Comment: @ZnewmaN: it's a no-brand device that apart from the missing logo looks identical to the Hyundai A7 ART

Comment: @Peanut: I am not sure what this "Customer Care" wording represents. Does it mean I should contact the company where I bought the tablet ? Does it mean I should post my question into some Google website ? Does it refer to a mobile provider which I don't have ? Is it one of the links in the http://play.google.com/ website ? Do you have a specific URL to refer me to ?

Comment: I'm not sure what it means, I suspect it means contact the company you bought it from, and it can't hurt to do that. If you do as @t0mm13b suggested and post a logcat of when you're trying to connect people on here may be able to offer more help.

Comment: @t0mm13b I will post the logcat as soon as I solve this other problem that I am getting after installing the Android SDK: upon launching Eclipse it says "Failed to create the Java Virtual Machine"

Comment: No need to do that! - on the command line - invoke `adb logcat`...

Comment: Now I am able to start up Eclipse after removing the lines with --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256M in eclipse.ini. Launching adb from the command line it just says - waiting for device - I suppose I need to install the OEM driver. The Vendor ID of the tablet is 18D1 and the Product ID is DEED, which makes it a Google device. Now I have to figure out which OEM driver to download...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot progress on creating the logcat until I solve the current problem that I reported [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43015/how-to-get-my-tablet-listed-by-adt)

Comment: @t0mm13b Finally I was able to create the **logcat**, which you can access [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46800854/mylog.zip)

Comment: To Clarify - *What* app was it that was showing the above error message? You define Skype and *other applications* - what were they?

Comment: Check if the date/time and time zone are set properly on the tablet.  Some services are known to reject connections that have those settings are out of sync.

Comment: @Chahk that's 100% true! Yes... Cannot see anything in the log... my only clue is that the Network error is associated with `I/GLSUser ( 4902): GLS error: NetworkError` in the log which is associated with Google Now+ hence my previous comment to yours.. [Here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35260/network-error-when-invoking-google-now)

Comment: @t0mm13b No app. Just trying to login to the Google Play Store and getting the error message

Comment: @Chahk The time zone is set to GMT+09:00 because now I am in Japan. The system language is set to English (Australia). When you say *out of sync* what do you mean ? sync with respect to what ? Actually I just found some setting related to *sync*: I have two accounts on this tablet, and for both of them I can see the wording "Sync is ON". Is that what you are referring to ?

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails.

So if you can't install apps from the google store. Then you can [sideload them with adb](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=22547792).
The apk can be found in backup folders from apps like 'titanium backup' so you can have your friend install it and back it up. then copy the apk.

I had a Cricket phone that I didn't buy service for... and they disabled the app "Google Voice" This sideload method worked to bypass that.

Comment: Unfortunately after all this time I am still stuck with the error `GLS error: NetworkError` I haven't found a way to connect to the Google Play Store yet. I wish there was a way of knowing for sure what is causing this error. I really need to download some apps, for example the VLC player, to verify some videostreaming in my current project. It's very frustrating that the approach to solving this error is to search the web for similar cases and try desperately to see if any of the solutions works for me too. The only progress I have made was to be able to run my own test application.

Comment: Interesting, it seems like you have no connectivity to the google servers. Poking around finds me [this..](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35260/network-error-when-invoking-google-now) You might try messing with your accounts. Also it might be useful to see if you can ping the google market server with a different device on your network... just to make sure that the ISP isn't blocking your request.