# How to get my tablet listed by adt

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, adb, usb-drivers

When I run `adb devices` from my Windows XP machine there is nothing listed. The tablet's Vendor ID is **18D1** and the Product ID is **DEED**. It gets enumerated as a USB device with a name **MID**. When I enable "USB storage" on the tablet, I can see the tablet's files in the Windows File Explorer as drive `G:` and the SD card on the tablet as drive `H:` -- however the Computer Management shows a big yellow question mark next to a device named "MID".

I searched for a suitable driver but all I could find was a list of drivers for well known brands. My tablet is a no-name version of the Hyundai A7 Art.

I've been struggling with this for quite a few days. My purpose is to collect a logcat to document another problem that I posted [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42852/is-it-possible-to-use-the-google-play-store-without-having-a-mobile-provider). I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging on the device? (`Settings -> Developer options -> USB debugging`)

Comment: Yes, it's enabled.

Comment: I have also tried to connect with *>adb connect 192.168.21.23* and I got the message *unable to connect to 192.168.21.23:5555* even though I get replies to *ping 192.168.21.23*

Comment: Do you have the correct device drivers installed? This may sound odd, but you can you try installing PDANet which includes drivers for a lot of devices (although your tablet may not be common enough) http://pdanet.co/ You can uninstall it after you have the correct drivers.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. I was just about to post about my success after installing [PDANet](http://www.topnotchtablets.com/installADBdriver), when I came to this page and found your message mentioning it :-) I am glad you told me I can now uninstall it, as I was not clear what the main purpose of that software is.

Answer (score -1):

Try to re-install the USB device driver for that specific tab, and try it once again.

Comment: That was exactly the problem: I didn't have a device driver to install. Anyway, I just solved it with PDANet (see above). Now I can move on and debug [why I cannot login to the Google Play Store](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42852/is-it-possible-to-use-the-google-play-store-without-having-a-mobile-provider)